# Android activity and fragments, best practice

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm about to make my first Android application and  I am currently reading about activities and fragments. I intend to use the Lollipop navigation drawer feature to load different screens in my application for different features. Like settings, About, Add new x, browse x, etc. Should my nav drawer be loading different activities for each item click or loading a new fragment?

All my screens will have the same style associated with them, but will have obviously much different content.

If I load a new activity, do I "lose" the nav drawer to the side? or is it always present as I want it to be accessible from any screen in the application.

I am quite unfamiliar with the Android system so far, but no matter what I choose do I need to use an intent to launch either of these. A real lay mans explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: Within one of my screens I hope to use a tab system and have it change.

[image]

This is a mockup I have designed, as you can see I would like the nav drawer to be used from this screen but also allow the switching of 3 different tabs, within the Add new timetable screen.

How would I go about having a tab at the top and then 3 different (linked) screens under it. This would be the deepest level I would go. Every other screen would just be one screen, no tabs.

Comment: So, how did it go? Did you solve the problem? If yes, choose an answer and accept it, or write your own answer if you solved it in a different way.

Comment: I never ended up solving it in the end, and went with a much different approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activity typically takes the whole screen, so yes, if you launch an Activity, you will temporarily "lose" everything that's placed in other activities.
Fragments, on the other hand, can be stuffed to smaller areas, and you can have several fragments on the screen at once.

Comment: Can I create every single activity with the nav drawer on it? I'm not too concerned with losing anything apart from the nav drawer.

Comment: @AlanGordon You can, but you shouldn't…

Comment: Is it better to Have a main activity with just the navdrawer on it, and then load different fragments compared to what is clicked in the navdrawer? Will that change the title bar at the top for the heading of a new page if I like?